How to steal focus from another app's text field?
I have written a calculator app. Its main window is a UIView subclass that usually receives user input from the touchscreen, tapping on a virtual keyboard (not the standard pop-up keyboard).
I recently added hardware keyboard support. In order to receive key events, I implemented canBecomeFirstResponder and made it always return YES, and I'm calling becomeFirstResponder whenever the main window becomes active, and resignFirstResponder when it becomes inactive.
This is working fine except for one scenario: when running the app on an iPad, together with another app, using Split View or Slide Over, and the other app has keyboard focus on a text field, my app doesn't receive keyboard events, even when it's the foreground app. I have to go into the other app, and tap somewhere outside a text field, and then return to my app, before my app is getting key events again.
If the user taps on an actual text field in my app, it gets focus just fine, of course, but apparently my UIView calling becomeFirstResponder is not enough to take away the focus from the other app.
Is there a way to steal the focus from another app's text field in this scenario?
UPDATE: To clarify, I'm not looking to go against the user's intents here. The object is not to eavesdrop or sabotage. The issue is that my UIView subclass tries to act like a text widget, and is unable to do so in one respect, namely, getting focus while another app has a focused text field while that other app is in the background. The fact that an app can continue to receive keyboard input, while the user has activated another app, seems wrong to me, and I am curious how UITextField can manage to obtain focus in this situation, while my class cannot.
UPDATE 2: The relevant code looks like this:
@interface CalcView : UIView {
    //
}

[...]

@implementation CalcView

[...]

- (void) setActive:(bool) active {
    if (active)
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
    else
        [self resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

// Keyboard handling (UIResponder methods)

// Tells this object when a physical button is first pressed.
- (void)pressesBegan:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent *)event {
    NSArray *p = [presses allObjects];
    bool handled = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < [p count]; i++) {
        UIPress *pr = [p objectAtIndex:i];
        // handle the key
    }
    if (!handled)
        [super pressesBegan:presses withEvent:event];
}

// Tells the object when a button is released.
- (void)pressesEnded:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent *)event {
    NSArray *p = [presses allObjects];
    // handle the events
    if (!handled)
        [super pressesEnded:presses withEvent:event];
}

// Tells this object when a value associated with a press has changed.
- (void)pressesChanged:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent *)event {
    // No need to handle this
    [super pressesChanged:presses withEvent:event];
}

// Tells this object when a system event (such as a low-memory warning) cancels a press event.
- (void)pressesCancelled:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent *)event {
    // No need to handle this
    [super pressesCancelled:presses withEvent:event];
}

The setActive method is called by the ViewController when it is made visible. I have intercepted the calls to [UIWindow makeKey] and [UIView becomeFirstResponder], and verified they are all getting called at the expected moment.
But if there is another app that's active side-by-side in Slide Over mode, and there is a textfield that has focus in that app (for example, the URL bar in Safari), then tapping on my app does not take the focus away from the other app. When I open another view in my app, one that contains a text field, and I set the focus on that text field, it does take the input away from the other app, as you would expect, and if I then return to the CalcView, it receives keyboard input. What I'm trying to figure out is what that textfield does to take focus away from the other app, and replicate that behavior in my CalcView class.

You can require full screen so that you do not share with another app using Split View or Slide Over.

The simple answer is no, you can't do that. The user has chosen to interact with the other app. You can't force the user to interact with yours. The user gets to choose which app they are currently using.

@HangarRash but the user has chosen to interact with my app, and still the keyboard input is going to the other one. I'm not trying to force the user to interact with my app, I'm trying to enable them to type at my app when they activate my app. If I were getting keyboard input into a UITextField, this would be perfectly normal and supported, but somehow another class can't do the same, even though it has declared itself the first responder.

It's very difficult for us to answer that question in light of the fact that you have shown us none of your code.

@matt I added the relevant code, and some additional clarification.
